How to create multiple different irregular cube 3D models in AnyLogic?
It seems that AnyLogic can only create 3D models similar to walls. I want to create irregular 3D cubic entities, which are a set of cubes cut from an irregular body. The cubes have varying heights, with some cubes having a consistent height that I will use for additional modeling above that elevation. I am modeling in Rhino and importing in .dae format, but AnyLogic shows a blank screen.
In fact, I am creating a 3D model of a dam to simulate the concrete pouring process using AnyLogic, and the cubes represent the concrete pouring segments of the dam. I am providing an example image that I created in Rhino, which is not a complete entity and is actually much more complex.
I want to know how to import 3D models from external sources into AnyLogic so that they display correctly, and if there are any good methods to import thousands of different cubes efficiently.

where's your example image?

sry ，it has been added

you can load and display any shapes if the data format is correct. See this post on how to show even the most complex photogrammetry, maybe this helps solving your issue: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/google-maps-photogrammetry
